# Why does my code say my object is not defined?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, instantiation

I'm new to C# and can't figure out why my class objects "do not exist" in the current contents.  I've tried multiple ways to reorganize and call my objects, but still get "The name 'ExcuteObject' does not exist in the current context.

```
namespace DBTest4
{
    class Program
    {
        class MacroInfo
        {
            public int MsgSN { get; set; }
            public int FormID { get; set; }
            public int Leg { get; set; }
            public int Stop { get; set; }

            public MacroInfo(DataRow row)
            {
                this.MsgSN = Convert.ToInt32(row["MsgSN"]);
                this.FormID = Convert.ToInt32(row["FormID"]);
                this.Leg = Convert.ToInt32(row["Leg"]);
                this.Stop = Convert.ToInt32(row["Stop"]);
            }
            public DataTable Ch(string commandsqlstring, bool isStoredProcedure = false)
            {
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                ......
                        return dataTable;
            }
            public IEnumerable<T> ExcuteObject<T>(string storedProcedureorCommandText, bool isStoredProcedure = true)
            {
                List<T> items = new List<T>();
                      .....
                return items;
            }

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {          
            string commandsqlstring = "Select top 10 MsgSN,FormID,Leg,Stop from tmail.MacroSendReceiveHistory order by ID desc";
            bool SP = false;
            List<MacroInfo> macroInfos = new List<MacroInfo>();
            macroInfos = ExcuteObject<MacroInfo>(commandsqlstring, SP).ToList();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Why is it not seeing Excute Object?

Comment: Erm, because it's in a nested class? You need first, a `MacroInfo`, then you can call `mi.ExecuteObject...` Or declare the function `static` then you can say `MacroInfo.ExecuteObject` And what is the point of ` = new List<MacroInfo>()` when you overwrite it in the next lin

Comment: I'm obviously very new.  I thought excuteobject was a method inside my class. In my lack of knowledge I've tried making each piece its own class, putting each piece inside the main, I'm obvously not understanding sth basic...

Comment: That's OK. Looks like you need to make it `static`, not sure why it is generic because you have provided no code, it can just create `MacroInfo`s and return the list. If it doesn't do anything related to `MacroInfo` it shouldn't be in that class.

Comment: The best help you can get is to learn and understand the basics of OOP, which you clearly need. You can find tons of resources online for that. Here's just one of them https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mkagrahari/introduction-to-object-oriented-programming-concepts-in-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ExcuteObject` is method of class `MacroInfo` and not method of class `Program`. Your current implementation would have worked if `ExcuteObject` method was static and was method of class "Program".

To fix this issue. You can do either of the following:

1. Move `ExcuteObject` method to `Program` class and make it static.
2. Keep `ExcuteObject` in `MacroInfo` class but make `ExcuteObject` method static and call it in `Program` class as `MacroInfo.ExcuteObject(...)`
3. Create an instance of `MacroInfo` class
   and call the the method on instance of `MacroInfo` class.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: @DanielleKugler, if this response answers you question then you mark it as answer. If it does not answer your question but still provides some help then you upvote it. Glad I was able to help.

Comment: So I moved both CH and ExcuteObject into Program (and made them static) and moved MacroInfo outside Program and finally got where I wanted to go.  Thanks for your assistance!